# How to get max values of table with sequelize model.findAll()

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a use case where have to store every change made to the Products table as a version of row that has changed. so my table consists of rows like below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXJ8S.png

So, when we use `model.findAll()` it will return all the rows including the version of each row. That would be fine for history view. here is the question, how can we get the all latest versions of rows in the table without returning previous versions(older changes) of it?. I'm a little concerned that we can use sequelize `max` attribute to achieve this. But not sure how it can be used to achieve my use case. can anyone please let me know how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before going to sequelize

There are several ways to go about it, although subquery is one of the ways you can do it.

I have demonstrated adding a subquery with max function in the where clause.

Let's first replicate it in simple mysql

```
mysql> create table product (productId VARCHAR(200), docversion integer, name VARCHAR(200), price integer, location VARCHAR(200));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.01 sec)

mysql> insert into product(productID, docversion, name, price, location) VALUES('PID123', 0, 'Chair', 25, 'USA');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into product(productID, docversion, name, price, location) VALUES('PID123', 1, 'Chair', 32, 'USA');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> insert into product(productID, docversion, name, price, location) VALUES('PID456', 0, 'Table', 39, 'UK');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> insert into product(productID, docversion, name, price, location) VALUES('PID456', 1, 'Table', 43, 'Canada');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> insert into product(productID, docversion, name, price, location) VALUES('PID123', 2, 'Chair', 29, 'UK');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> select * from product;
+-----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
| productId | docversion | name  | price | location |
+-----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
| PID123    |          0 | Chair |    25 | USA      |
| PID123    |          1 | Chair |    32 | USA      |
| PID456    |          0 | Table |    39 | UK       |
| PID456    |          1 | Table |    43 | Canada   |
| PID123    |          2 | Chair |    29 | UK       |
+-----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from product where  location='USA' AND name='Chair' AND docversion = (select max(docversion) from product where location='USA' AND name='Chair' group by productId);
+-----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
| productId | docversion | name  | price | location |
+-----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
| PID123    |          1 | Chair |    32 | USA      |
+-----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Now converting the same query to sequelize

```
product.findAll({
  where: {
      location:{
          [Op.eq]: 'USA',
      },
      name:{
          [Op.eq]: 'Chair',
      },
      docversion:{
          [Op.eq]: sequelize.literal(`select max(docversion) from product where location='USA' AND name='Chair' group by productId`),
      },
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for answering in detail. I just wanted to list all products(latest version) in the table without any further where condition. Can we get that? Thanks

Comment: Yeah you can remove any condition from that, should be easy
product.findAll({
  where: {
      docversion:{
          [Op.eq]: sequelize.literal(select max(docversion) from product where group by productId),
      },
  }

Although, if you don't need ANY where condition, then You might need to create subquery in FROM part

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. can you please let me know. getting ```syntax error at or near 'select'```

Comment: Missed backticks there 
 product.findAll({ where: { docversion:{ [Op.eq]: sequelize.literal(\`select max(docversion) from product where group by productId\`), }, } )

Comment: throwing an error: ```more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression```. Then tried with ```OP.in```, it is returning duplicate values too ie. previous version of same document. is there any way, we can prevent duplicates with max groupby?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you can use for this problem. I add where condition too in case you need it with where condition.

```
Product.findAll({
  attributes: [
    "ProductId",
    "Name",
    "Price",
    "Location",
    [sequelize.fn("max", sequelize.col("docVersion")), "latestDocVersion"],
  ],
  where: {
    Location: "USA"
  },
  raw: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group` and `having` clauses in `findAll` method.

```
product.findAll({
  attributes: ['productId', 'name', 'price', 'location', 'docversion'],
  group: ['productId'],
  having: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('max', sequelize.col('docversion')), '=', sequelize.col('docversion'))
});
```

In this query, `group` clause will group the products with the same `productId`, which means all the product version with that Id will be grouped. From that group, the product with the max version will be selected by filtering using `having` clause.